VS Code shows "No such file or directory" when I "Run" a Python script but executes it successfully after "Run and Debug"
I am new to programming and I wanted to find an explanation for something I found odd in VS Code.
I was trying to execute a piece of Python script that looks functional, but found the error "No such file or directory" when I "Run" the code. The code involves reading a csv file and I tried to use different formats of relative and direct reference for the csv file to no success, so I turned the csv file into a text file and tried to do the same. The odd thing is the code only executed when I "Run and Debug" it using Python Debugger.
You can see below the lines I was stuck on when I tried "Run" with the csv reading lines commented out because it was not working:
    # csv_read_path = 'TherJPR_Drugs.csv'
    # with open(csv_read_path, 'rb') as csv_read:
    #   txt = csv.reader(csv_read)
    txt_path = 'TherJPR_Drugs.txt'
    with open(txt_path, encoding='utf-8-sig') as f: # the utf-8-sig handles UTF-8 with BOM encoding
        txt = f.read().splitlines() # the splitlines() get rid of the \n at the end of lines

The error generated was:
with open(txt_path, encoding='utf-8-sig') as f: # the utf-8-sig handles UTF-8 with BOM encoding    
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'TherJPR_Drugs.txt'

My main question: Why do I get this error on "Run" but not on "Run and Debug" with Python Debugger?
But also, the csv reading code lines seem to work on "Run and Debug" but for the for loop a few lines below that makes use of the csv.reader output already saved in a variable (txt). I get an error at the beginning of the for loop that shows "readline of closed file":
ValueError after csv.reader
And when I tried to place the for loop (and a couple lines between the csv.reader and the for loop) within the "with open(..." block for the csv.reader function, I get the following error:
ValueError 2 on for loop
It says the file needs to be opened as text, but there has to be a way to read it as csv, right?
I'm sure I'm missing something.
I would appreciate your help on this.
Thanks,
Simon

CSV files are text files.  They are not binary.  Change the 'rb' to 'r'.

The csv.reader stores the handle to the input file so it can read from it later, when you need it.  When your with statement ends, it closes the handle, so the reader can no longer access it, just as the error message says.

Thank you @TimRoberts for your feedback! Changing the rb to r helped me to progress further into the for loop to be able to execute successfully with "Run and Debug".
Within with open(... block, I ended up  using the output from csv.reader to feed into the next lines which have writer.writerow function. My problem there was that I was trying to .split(',') the csv.reader output (txt) when it was already a list:
for txt_line in txt : for j in txt_line.split(',') : row.append(j)
I simply used writer.writerow(txt_line) in the place of the last two lines and it worked.

the error is displayed at runtime but there is no error in running and debugging, you can see if the program outputs in the terminal panel, and you can see the error in the problem panel. Here are a few steps you can take to change code:

First of all, since CSV files are usually stored in text format. You need to change rb to r or add newline=''.
Add encoding='utf-8-sig'.
Perform the cycle inside with.


Thank you for your response @Jeanneli.
I already included your 3 suggestions yesterday when I was tinkering more with it and I progressed further towards execution. The "No such file or directory" error persisted, but I was finally able to complete the run execution when I used a direct reference to the csv files I was reading from and writing to (I'm not sure if I needed to do that for the csv file to write to):
csv_read_path = r'C:\...TherJPR_MSDrugs.csv'     with open(csv_read_path, 'r', newline='', encoding='utf-8-sig') as csv_read:
Thank you.

I tried to change the path of the csv file to write to into relative reference, since the py file is in the same folder as both csv files, but I was not able to see the csv file output in the folder after successful execution - don't know which black hole it disappeared into.

Hello, yes, the reference needs to be within that method. I tried it and the relative path was successful when the py file and the two csv files were in the same level of folder. In the py file, the file path for the csv is written like csv_read_path = 'TherJPR_Drugs.csv'.

I guess you are not working in your Folder. If you created a file without setting a Working directory, VSCode works in Python installation directory . From VS studio Code open your folder that you are working in. You can check it from explorer on the left panel.
